# Styling Angular Records Based on Status of Front-end State

Tags: angular, ng-class

In my Angular front-end app I have a list of records which I'm displaying via `*ngFor`, like so:

```
<tr *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: getPageNumber() }">
```

The list shows records of a certain `status`. So I have one grid view for records where `status` is equal to `processing`, another one where `status` is equal to `completing`, etc.

We now have a new spec to meet where a record should be bolded in the grid view *prior* to being clicked on for the first time. In other words, if I change a record's `status` from `processing` to `completing`, then in my grid view for `status: completing` records, the line representing that new record should have bold styling until a user clicks on that record for the first time. From then on the grid view should display that record just like the others, with a `font-weight` set to `normal`.

I understand that for something like Angular forms you can use `markAsPristine()` and `markAsTouched()` to style your output as needed. But how would I handle this in a grid view like this? And to clarify, there is no database property I can rely on here. This needs to rely on front-end properties and state only.

And one added requirement: this need to apply across all front-end users. This is an internal app. So we have several people looking at the grid list. If one user clicks on a record, then all users should subsequently see that record as unbolded in the grid view. Any idea as to how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

```
You need a style binding.

<tr *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: getPageNumber() }" 
[style.font-weight]="record?.status === 'processing' ? '300' : 'bold'">
</tr>
```

### Also you can try *ngIf=""

```
<div *ngIf="some condition"> 
   <tr *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: getPageNumber() }">
</div>

<div *ngIf="some other condition"> 
   <tr *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: getPageNumber() }">
</div>
```

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the question.

Comment: Show me the json schema

Comment: How would that help? Again, to clarify, the challenge is not the displaying of records with a certain "status". That part's done. The issue is bold styling those records that haven't been clicked on yet in the front-end list view.

Comment: Re: the `*ngIf`, what would "some condition" refer to? Again, that's the challenge.

Comment: First I dont work for you, second show me what you have and what you want to have, (an image, a stretch, something)
By showing exactly what you want to see, is more helpful by telling all your story here

Comment: George, no offense, but no one said you work for me. I'm saying I think you're misunderstanding the question. That's all. I described the situation. It's based purely on front-end state, so there's nothing I can bind to in terms of database properties on the record. Anyway, misunderstandings happen. I'd recommend deleting this answer, as it doesn't address the actual challenge.

Comment: this answer will not be deleted, your question is about styling base on status, this is why I show the style binding based on condition.
if my answer does not help you, will help other people related to this.

Comment: George, the question is NOT about styling based on `status`. That's what you're misunderstanding. It's about styling based on the `touched` or `pristine` front-end state of a record in a grid list view.

Comment: an ok, you must add an event listener base on the mouse or even better an animation

Comment: also one whey is to store this information inside the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a property in record (for example: wasClickedFirsTime), and you can do something like this:

```
<tr (click)="record.wasClickedFirsTime = true" [ngClass]="{'is-bold': !record.wasClickedFirsTime}" *ngFor="let record of records | paginate: { id: 'customers', itemsPerPage: 12, currentPage: getPageNumber() }">
```

And of course:

```
.is-bold {
    font-weight : bold
}
```

Comment: Are you suggesting I actually add this property to the record in the database, or somehow store it in front-end state only?

Comment: If you want the change to be reflected online for all users, I think it is necessary to add this property to the record in the database. I do not see another way, but how could the other users find out?

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out. But, from my understanding, adding a property to the database record purely for the sake of front-end navigation would be considered bad practice.

Comment: Disagree on the "bad practice" issue. Doesn't matter what device I log in from, GMail knows which emails have been read, and which not. It's not bad practice, it's pretty much standard.

Answer (score 0):

> We now have a new spec to meet where a record should be bolded in the grid view prior > to being clicked on for the first time.

That one's easy. You can add a boolean `clicked` property to elements of the `records` collection, or store the ids of the clicked elements in an array, whichever looks neater to you.

> And one added requirement: this need to apply across all front-end users. This is an 
>   internal app. So we have several people looking at the grid list. If one user clicks 
>   on a record, then all users should subsequently see that record as unbolded in the 
>   grid view.

And this one is tricky. The only answer I can think of is WebRTC. I believe it meets the requirements: client-to-client communication without the server's participation.

Check if something like this
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-webrtc
will work for you.

But: if Alice clicks on **`Item 1`** now, and Bob logs in an hour from now and should see `Item 1` as clicked, *that* I think can't be done without server side providing the persistence.